# event handling for ajax loaded elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, event-handling

I have some `select` tags, some loaded via ajax, I bind a handler to their `change` event on document `ready`, so those loaded via ajax miss the registration.

What should I do?

Can I use event propagation like when the event was `click`, I mean does `change` of a `select` child,  propagate to its `div` parent?

or

Should I also include a script tag in the ajax response that has the `select` element to bind the handler to the that after being inserted in the document?

or

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [event delegation](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2010/03/4/event-delegation-with-jquery) techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for jQuery [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function?